# Angular 2+ (v11) automatically encode fragment hash (#) in URL into %23

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular11

My Angular app has to automatically scroll (only Y-axis) to a certain component when a corresponding hash exists in the URL.

E.g. `url.com/page1#element1` should make the browser automatically scrolls to Element 1, naturally with `#element1` inside the HTML tag.

But somehow my Angular app automatically replaces the hash (#) with %23, its URL-encoded version. This causes the problem that my app cannot recognise any fragment in the URL (I use `this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe()` to get the fragment value) I tried checking everywhere in the code, but I can't seem to find the source of the problem. Does anybody have any possible solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a fix, but I think this is a problem specific to my app. So I basically have 2 mode of my app, one is the normal `ng serve` and the other one is SSR mode (server side rendering). Basically this problem only shows up in the normal mode, but if I run the app with the SSR mode (also what I have in prod), the hash is being kept as-is.